# Extraction with names when names are repetitive

Tags: r, extract, data-manipulation

I came across this challenge. How to extract when there is repetition in names?

```
X <- 1:5
names(X) <- c(letters[1:4], "a")
X
a b c d a 
1 2 3 4 5
names(X)
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "a"

X["a"]
a 
1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract when there is repetition in `names`:

```
X[names(X) %in% "a"]
# a a 
# 1 5
```

Why is R accepting repetitive names?

Note that `names` is a generic accessor function. You can set a `names` to anything, it doesn't really have to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Other solutions:

```
X[grepl("a", names(X))]
X[names(X) == "a"]
```

Also in general it is better to have unique names, so
you can reference them without confusion. 
The following command does it for you.

```
make.unique(names(X))
[1] "a"   "b"   "c"   "d"   "a.1"
```

BTW the first of the solution I proposed above, would still pick
all the columns that contain `a`.